# remove formating from text in html

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to remove text decoration from text. Underline is removed but when I move cursor on text the color is displayed over the text. So how do I remove this color?

Here is the code:

```
messbox
{
    background-color: #C2E1EE;
    border: 1px solid;
    padding-top: 20px;
    border-color: #8EC3D9;
    margin-left: 40px;
    margin-right: 150px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}
.message_box_title
{
    color:#475D66;
    font-size:16px;
    font-family:Candara;
    font-weight:bold;
    margin-left: 12px;
    margin-top: -10px;
}    
.contectmessage a
{ 
    color:#2A84AE;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-family:Candara;
    margin-left:12px;       
}
```

...and here is the image:

[image]

Comment: `messbox` - is this a _class_ or _id_? there is no dot (`.`) or hash (`#`) in front...

Comment: post the markup please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use **[`:hover`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover)** pseudo-class selector

```
.contectmessage a:hover,.contectmessage a:active
{ 
    color:#2A84AE;
    text-decoration:none; 
    background-color:transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
.contectmessage a:hover {
    text-decoration:none;     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
.contectmessage a:hover {
    text-decoration:none; 
    background-color:transparent;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.contectmessage a:hover {
    text-decoration:none; 
    background-color:transparent;

}
```

it seems you have declared some where the background color onhover, kindly search this #54879d in your code and remove it or else paste your code in jsfiddle.net so that we can get a right solution..